# PyTest: fix repeating code and remove dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, rest, pytest

I am writing tests for an API with pytest. 
The tests are structured like that:

```
KEEP_BOX_IDS = ["123abc"]

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def s():
    UID = os.environ.get("MYAPI_UID")
    if UID is None:
        raise KeyError("UID not set in environment variable")
    PWD = os.environ.get("MYAPI_PWD")
    if PWD is None:
        raise KeyError("PWD not set in environment variable")
    return myapi.Session(UID, PWD)



@pytest.mark.parametrize("name,description,count", [
    ("Normal Box", "Normal Box Description", 1),
    ("ÄäÖöÜüß!§", "ÄäÖöÜüß!§", 2),
    ("___--_?'*#", "\n\n1738\n\n", 3),
])
def test_create_boxes(s, name, description, count):
    box_info_create = s.create_box(name, description)
    assert box_info_create["name"] == name
    assert box_info_create["desc"] == description
    box_info = s.get_box_info(box_info_create["id"])
    assert box_info["name"] == name
    assert box_info["desc"] == description
    assert len(s.get_box_list()) == count + len(KEEP_BOX_IDS)


def test_update_boxes(s):
    bl = s.get_box_list()
    for b in bl:
        b_id = b['id']
        if b_id not in KEEP_BOX_IDS:
            new_name = b["name"] + "_updated"
            new_desc = b["desc"] + "_updated"
            s.update_box(b_id, new_name, new_desc)
            box_info = s.get_box_info(b_id)
            assert box_info["name"] == new_name
            assert get_box_info["desc"] == new_desc
```

I use a fixture to set up the session (this will keep me connected to the API).

As you can see I am creating 3 boxes at the beginning.
All test that are following do some sort of operations on this 3 boxes. (Boxes are just spaces for folders and files)

For example: update_boxes, create_folders, rename_folders, upload_files, change_file names, etc..

I know it's not good, since all the tests are dependent from each other, but if I execute them in the right order the test is valid and thats enough.

The second issue, which borders me the most, is that all the following tests start with the same lines:

```
bl = s.get_box_list()
for b in bl:
    b_id = b['id']
    if b_id not in KEEP_BOX_IDS:
        box_info = s.get_box_info(b_id)
```

I always need to call this for loop to get each boxs id and info.
I've tried to put it in a second fixture, but the problem is that then there will be two fixtures.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I got it right, but you can create a fixture that uses another fixture as argument, e.g. `def box_create(s): ...`. To break up the dependencies between tests, you should use the [fixture finalization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code), e.g. the fixture`box_create` creates the boxes, yields and removes the added boxes after the test finishes. This will ensure that each test starts with the same data setup.